# When using php, why does $_SESSION['cust_id'] = 123; create a variable called $cust_id? (PHP v5.3.29)

Tags: php, session

Why does $_SESSION['cust_id'] = 123;  create a variable called $cust_id also containing 123?

Isn't $_SESSION['cust_id']  and  $cust_id supposed to be two different variables?

phpversion: 5.3.29
register_globals: ON

Example Code:

```
<?php
        
        session_start();
        
        $_SESSION['cust_id'] = 1;           // sets $_SESSION['cust_id'] 1 = all good
        
        echo $_SESSION['cust_id'] . "<br>";    // returns 1 = all good
        
        $cust_id = $_SESSION['cust_id'];      // sets $cust_id 1 = all good     //note this is not =&
 
        echo $cust_id . "<br>";               // returns 1 = all good
        
        echo $_SESSION['cust_id'] . "<br>";    // returns 1 = all good
        
        $cust_id = 5;                          // He is going to use this variable for something else for a little bit. should be ok.

        echo $cust_id . "<br>";               // returns 5 = all good
        
        echo $_SESSION['cust_id'] . "<br>";    // He expected this to still hold 1, because he haden't changed the session variable at all
                                               // returns 5!!!  what the...  $cust_id wasn't a reference to the session object surely? the original developer didn't expect that.
        
        echo "phpversion: " . phpversion() . "<br>";
        
        echo "ini_get('register_globals'): " . ini_get('register_globals') . "<br>";
```

Output:

```
1
1
1
5
5
phpversion: 5.3.29
ini_get('register_globals'): 1
```

Comment: cannot reproduce: output `11151`

Comment: Same as @lovelace here

Comment: I am getting this as output after running it , kindly check
1
1
1
5
1

Comment: see [demo 3v4L](https://3v4l.org/kgp50) - output `11151`

Comment: I see this: https://imgur.com/a/slgj9KR

Comment: So, I guess the problem is with your local session or something like this.

Comment: I could understand this if you had instead: `cust_id = &$_SESSION['cust_id'];`, but I cannot duplicate this.

Comment: PHP directive `register_globals` went from `ON` to `OFF` in `PHP » 4.2.0`. This feature has been `DEPRECATED` as of `PHP 5.3.0` and `REMOVED` as of PHP `5.4.0`.

Comment: Thanks lovelace, so the creation of global variables when using session variables changed in PHP 4.2 to OFF (took 4.2 versions to come to their senses, because this is really crazy).     My webhost must still have register_globals ON when using php 5.3.29.   This is not an issue for those above who are using php 5.4 or higher.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Some php 5.3 web hosts have REGISTER_GLOBALS turned ON (in php.ini)

which causes $_SESSION['cust_id'] to also create an internal variable called $cust_id  with the same value.

PHP 5.4 OR HIGHER has it hardcoded to OFF